# How can I append an Eloquent property from a related model without getting the model's contents?

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent

I have 2 eloquent models:

```
EloquentUser
```

and

```
SharedEvents
```

They are both related by user_id

I'm attempting to set up and appends attribute in the SharedEvents model that will append the full_name of the user with whom the event has been shared.

For the sake of readability, I'm only including the appends components of my class

```
class SharedEvents extends Model {

protected $appends      = ['fullName'];

/**
 * @return BelongsTo
 */
public function user() : BelongsTo {
    return $this->belongsTo('Path\To\EloquentUser', 'shared_with_id', 'user_id');
}

    /**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getFullNameAttribute(){
    return $this->user->user_full_name;
}
```

Unfortunately when I run this I'm getting back both the full name and the entire user model when I only want the full name.

Is there a way to avoid attaching the content of the user model?

Comment: Can you show us the code where you're calling the `getFullNameAttribute()` accessor?

Comment: So it gets called automatically via an query. I can show it but it's a pretty hair query..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It feels like you're trying to make columns from your `EloquentUser` model first class citizens in your `SharedEvent` model. You're getting close, but consider...

When working with relationships, this is a good way to be explicit:

Assuming `user_full_name` is an accessor on your `User` model:

```
// EloquentUser.php

// This will automatically add your accessor to every query 
// as long as you select the columns the accessor is made 
// up of
protected $appends = ['user_full_name'];

/**
 * User Full Name Accessor

 * @return string
 */
public function getUserFullNameAttribute()
{
    return $this->first_name . ' ' . $this->last_name;
}

// SharedEvent.php

/**
 * A SharedEvent belongs to an Eloquent User

 * @return BelongsTo
 */
public function user() : BelongsTo 
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Path\To\EloquentUser', 'shared_with_id', 'user_id');
}

// Somewhere in your controller or wherever you want to access the data
$sharedEvents = SharedEvent::with(['user' => function ($query) {
    $query->select('user_id', 'first_name', 'last_name');
}])->where(...)->get(['shared_with_id', ...other columns]); // you must select the related column here
```

This should get you the closest to what you want, but there are a couple of things you should know:

1. If `user_full_name` is an accessor, you need to select all of the columns that make up that accessor (as I mention above)
2. You must select the related keys (`user_id` in `EloquentUser` and `shared_with_id` in `SharedEvent`)
3. The `$appends` is necessary in `EloquentUser` here because you can't directly add an accessor to your sub query inside the closure.

Try to get comfortable with using a closure as the 2nd argument in your relationships. It's the best way to really be precise as to which columns you're selecting when you're loading relationships — Eloquent makes it really easy to be lazy and just do:

```
SharedEvent::with('user')->get();
```

which as you've see will just do a `select *` on both `SharedEvent` and  your `user` relationship.

Another thing I've noticed when working with complex queries that use relationships is that you can quickly reach a point where it feels like you're fighting the framework. That's often a sign to consider simplifying ot just using raw SQL. Eloquent is powerful, but is just another tool in your programming tool belt. Remember that you have other tools at your disposal.

Comment: Excellent answer, I've felt the same way myself at times.I think in the exact scenario I have here I'm going to stick with running an extra query for these cases. The rest of my API is relying on the result being a laravel collection, and everything other than this particular field works just fine. I'm going to accept your answer because of your thoughtful analysis. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Glad I could help. This will still be an Eloquent Collection, but maybe there's some other details I'm missing. Good luck!

Comment: You're correct, it would be an eloquent collection I was just remarking that I am indeed relying on the API.

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the same problem, and my first idea was to explicitly hide the (entire) associated model when fetching *SharedEvent*.

In your case, this would look like:

```
class SharedEvents extends Model {

   protected $appends  = ['fullName'];
   protected $hidden   = ['user'];
   ...
}
```

I actually decided against this since I am returning a lot of other attached models, so I decided on attaching the entire user, but I tested it and it works.

FYI, I'm not sure if the discrepancy is due to an older version of Laravel, but Eloquent actually expects $appends attributes to be in snake-case (https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json):

> Note that attribute names are typically referenced in "snake case", even though the accessor is defined using "camel case"

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
public function user() : BelongsTo {
    return $this->belongsTo('Path\To\EloquentUser', 'shared_with_id', 'user_id')->select('fullName','user_id');
}
```

Comment: I did try that, but unfortunately got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research and experimentation, it doesn't look like there's a way to do this with Eloquent. The solution I ended up going with unfortunately is running an additional query.

```
/**
 * This is inefficient, but I could not find a way to get the full name
 * attribute without including all of user.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getFullNameAttribute(){
    return EloquentUser::select('user_full_name')
                        ->where('user_id', $this->shared_with_id)
                        ->first()
                        ->user_full_name;
}
```

Comment: Eloquent relationships don't simply perform joins. In fact, they will ALWAYS perform additional queries. That's a big part of how Eloquent does what it does. If you choose to use Eloquent, it's up to you to learn how to control how those queries can be most efficient. Check out [Laravel Debug Bar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) and you'll start to get a really good understanding of what Eloquent is doing behind the scenes.